# REST URIs for filesystem-like resources

Tags: rest

We are working on a REST service that provides access to resources structured similar to a file system, i.e. they are arranged in a tree-like hierarchy with no fixed depth or naming conventions. Accessing a resource would look like

```
GET /repository/path/to/resource
```

i.e. the path part after `/repository` is the unique identifier for the resource. Now comes the problem: each resource also has properties such as permissions. The natural way to query the permission would be

```
GET /repository/path/to/resource/permissions
```

However, what if there is a resource named `/path/to/resource/permissions`? I guess you see the problem. The only solution that comes to my mind is to put the resources properties in a separate hierarchy, e.g.

```
GET /permissions/path/to/resource
```

but that doesn't look correct. Any ideas how to deal with the problem?

Comment: I'm no REST expert, but the second option seems like the best option to me. Why would you say it doesn't look correct?

Comment: You could also try url encoding it, so `/repository/path/to/resource/permissions` becomes `/repository/path%2Fto%2Fresource/permissions`, but I ran into issues with special characters like that and using mod_rewrite. See my question here: http://serverfault.com/questions/683107/how-do-you-prevent-mod-rewrite-from-decoding-a-string-in-the-path/683109#683109

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are relying on URI semantics for determining something. In REST that shouldn't be a problem, because your clients are expected to get the location of the resource responsible for the permissions as a link somewhere else. When you follow a link, it doesn't matter where the resource is. It might even be in another system or using another protocol.

There's nothing wrong with the option `GET /permissions/path/to/resource` as long as the representation for `GET /repository/path/to/resource` says that's where the permissions are.

If you're not using HATEOAS and you don't want to use it, then using a query parameter is probably the simplest option.

Comment: True, but ideally the URIs also represent the object hierarchy and a permission is clearly a part of a workflow. After all most URIs do carry some meaning otherwise you could use just random characters. I was hoping that there is a magic bullet solution for such problems that somebody has already come up with.

Comment: You **can** just use random characters. URIs are atomic identifiers. Period. If you are using them to determine hierarchy and permission, you are doing something wrong. The magic bullet you are looking for is HATEOAS, which is an essential part of REST. What you are describing isn't a problem at all in REST.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a query parameter:

```
GET /repository/path/to/resource?properties=permissions
```

If there are other properties, you could query for them like this:

```
GET /repository/path/to/resource?properties=permissions,size
```